# Catch undefined index from MongoDB document Laravel

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel

**Hi everyone!** The documents within my MongoDB collection can differ. Some have an extra embedded document called `Additional_Information`. I would like the web browser to display a table of the information within the `Additional_Information` when this is available, and to ignore it when it's not found! This should be the easiest if-statement, but I can't get it to work. I have tried this code:

```
@if (is_array($document['Additional_Information']))
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#busco">Additional Information</a></li>
@endif
```

It does display the `Additional Information` tab when it is available. But when it is not, an `Undefined index: Additional_Information` it thrown! Does someone know how I can make this distinction between documents and catch when it's not there?

Comment: Is that code supposed to be PHP? Or does Mongo have it's own thing here?

Comment: @Machavity I think `@if` and `@endif` is Blade syntax (Laravel's template engine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) instead:

```
@if (!empty($document['Additional_Information']))
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#busco">Additional Information</a></li>
@endif
```

According to the documentation:

> No warning is generated if the variable does not exist. That means empty() is essentially the concise equivalent to !isset($var) || $var == false.

Comment: I knew it has to be something simple! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you need to use **array_key_exists** as well in order to check if key **Additional_Information** exists or not in the array **$document**